# Node WritableStream does not cascade directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, filesystems

I am writing to a log file `my.log` using a writestream `fs.createWriteStream('my.log', {flags: 'a'})`.

At the same time I have another code snippet which is using `fs.createReadStream()` to read the `my.log` file, however, this one doesnt seem to get the updates as soon as the log file is written to. Only when I manually open and close the file on my OS (windows), it gets triggered.

What do I do to make this trigger happen instantly? Do I reopen and close the writestream every time like:

```
var strm = fs.createWriteStream('my.log', {flags: 'a'})
// log my data
strm.close();
// rinse and repeat
```

Comment: Did you try to [pipe](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe) them?

Comment: This isn't a built-in feature of streams.  A read stream reads to the end of the stream, then closes the stream.  It doesn't constantly watch for more bytes to show up at the end.

Comment: You might find this package [tail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail) to be useful either to use directly or to examine to see how they do it.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, I've been using a read stream that supports tailing the file, that is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-tail-stream , so I create it using `fs.createReadStream(...,{tail:true})` which does the job. However it still doesnt get the trigger. I'll try out your linked package.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this boils down to an issue within Node/Windows:

- "fs.watch API is not 100% consistent across platforms, and is unavailable in some situations"
- "On Windows systems, this feature depends on ReadDirectoryChangesW."

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_availability

So as a solution, ive now used:

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail
var Tail = require('tail').Tail;
// Pass property to force the usage of fs.watchFile
tail = new Tail('my.log', { useWatchFile: true });
```

If you dont want to use the package "tail", then you should manually use `fs.watchFile` and act accordingly on file changes.